# How to Expand UITableview cell without collapse other cell(multiple cell expand) in swift

Tags: ios, swift

When we click on table view cell it will expand but if other `cells` are already expanded they will not collapse means we can see all `cells` expanded at a time..

i used below code for single `cell` expand but not getting how to do for multiple `cell`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex && thereIsCellTapped {
            switch indexPath.row{
            case 0:
                return 119
            case 1:
                return 93
            case 2:
                return 117
            case 3:
                return 135
            case 4:
                return 93
            case 5:
                return 230
            default:
                return 140
            }
        }
        return 55
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! PatientDetailsTableViewCell

        if indexPath.section == 2 {
        self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        if self.selectedRowIndex != -1 {
            self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: self.selectedRowIndex, inSection: 2))?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }

        if indexPath.section == 2 && selectedRowIndex != indexPath.row {
            self.thereIsCellTapped = true
            self.selectedRowIndex = indexPath.row

            currentCell.lblRightArrow.text = "P"
            print(selectedRowIndex)
        }
        else {
            // there is no cell selected anymore
            self.thereIsCellTapped = false
            self.selectedRowIndex = -1
            currentCell.lblRightArrow.text = "p"
        }
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
```

I used that code for expanding single `cell` but how to do for multiple `cell` I am not getting

please help....thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the code that you have used, and the code you have used to  try to fix the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After too much work i got the solution for expanding multiple cell so i am sharing here to help others..

for expanding cell you have to store the indexPath in array when click on cell then use that array at tableview delegate method for height.My code is below..

```
var selectedIndexPath : NSIndexPath?
var indexPaths : Array<NSIndexPath> = []
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    if !indexPaths.contains(selectedIndexPath!){
            indexPaths += [selectedIndexPath!]
    }
    else {
        let index = indexPaths.indexOf(selectedIndexPath!)
        indexPaths.removeAtIndex(index!)
    }
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPaths.count>0 {
        if indexPaths.contains(indexPath){
            return 200
        }
        else {
            return 50
        }
    }
      return 50
}
```

Comment: Thank you for tableView.beginUpdates();tableView.endUpdates()!!! Absolutely forgot about this.. It`s rly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file named as TableViewController subclass of `UITableViewController` and also take a `UITableViewController` from `storyboard` and assign the class TableViewController from Identity Inspector of `Xcode` and also name the cell identifier as `Cell`. Then implement the class bellow:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var groupArray = [String]()
var boolArray : [String]!
var dataDic = [String : [String]]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
groupArray = ["A","B","C"]
boolArray = [String](count: groupArray.count, repeatedValue: "0")
let groupA = ["CELL ONE","CELL TWO","CELL THREE","CELL FOUR","CELL FIVE"]
let groupB = ["CELL ONE","CELL TWO","CELL THREE","CELL FOUR","CELL FIVE"]
let groupC = ["CELL ONE","CELL TWO","CELL THREE","CELL FOUR","CELL FIVE"]
dataDic["A"] = groupA
dataDic["B"] = groupB
dataDic["C"] = groupC

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
   return groupArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:   Int) -> Int{
 let boolForSec = boolArray[section] as String
 if (Int(boolForSec) != 0) {
   var arr = dataDic[groupArray[section]]
   return arr!.count
 }else {
   return 0
 }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath:  indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

 let boolForSec = boolArray[indexPath.section] as String
 if (Int(boolForSec) != 0) {
   var arr : [String] = dataDic[groupArray[indexPath.section]]!
   cell.textLabel?.text = arr[indexPath.row] as String
 }else {

 }

 // cell.textLabel?.text = "row \(indexPath.row)"
 return cell
}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

  return 50
 }

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
   return 1
 }

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
   headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
   headerView.tag = section

  let headerString = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width:     tableView.frame.size.width-10, height: 30)) as UILabel
  headerString.text = groupArray[section] as String
  headerView .addSubview(headerString)

  let headerTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer (target: self,    action:"sectionHeaderTapped:")
   headerView .addGestureRecognizer(headerTapped)

      return headerView
  }

  func sectionHeaderTapped(tapped: UITapGestureRecognizer){

     let section = tapped.view?.tag
     let boolForSec = boolArray[section!] as String
      if (Int(boolForSec) != 0) {
         boolArray[section!] = "0"

      }else {
         boolArray[section!] = "1"

      }

   tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: section!), withRowAnimation:  UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    }

     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
     }

  }
```

Comment: Hi Md.Muzahidul Islam your solution is good but it will not work for me because i have 3 custom cell for 3 section and one of them section having 5 cell which will expand with their subviews. so i want all 5 cell will be expanded at a time...

Comment: Hi, I have made some change in viewDidLoad method. Now three section and each section has five cell as you told.